# Find by less than or greater than in underscore.js

Tags: underscore.js

We are using underscore.js using AngularJS .We use _.where to find the data

```
$scope.myData=[{age:15}]
```

So , to find from it we are using

```
_.where($scope.myData,{age:15})
```

but to find something like  _.where($scope.myData,{age<15}) ,it gives error , is there any way to do .Or we have to go with _.filter

```
_.filter($scope.myData,function(val){
    if(val.age<20)
    {
     return val
    }})
```

Comment: Filter is the right way to go as you are filtering the collection. Where and it's cousin findWhere only take an object. Create a predicate called something like isChild e.g. function isChild(person) { return person.age < 18; } and use it as the second parameter to _.filter e.g. var children = _.filter($scope.myData, isChild).

Comment: Keep in mind that `where` is little more than a front end for `filter` which converts an object into a function which tests properties for equality. If equality isn't what you're after then `where` isn't the right tool.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you can see from the Underscore source code, `where` is really sugar for `filter`

```
_.where = function(obj, attrs) {
  return _.filter(obj, _.matches(attrs));
};
```

http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html#section-28

So, yes, you should use `filter`!

```
_.filter(myArray, function(v) { return v.age < 15 })
```

Comment: Ohhh internally they also use the filter , so best option is to use _.filter . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We can use _.filter OR _.find function of Underscore to accomplish this.

```
_.filter($scope.myData, function(v) { return  (60 >= v.Age && 94 <= v.Age)})

_.find($scope.myData, function(v){ return (60 >= v.Age && 94 <= v.Age) });
```